# Listening for both IPv6 and IPv4 in apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, ipv6

I'm using apache2.2

How to listen both Ipv6 and Ipv4?

or

only Ipv6 / only Ipv4

Answer (score 8):

Apache supports multiple Listen options:

```
Listen 192.170.2.1:80
Listen 192.170.2.5:8000
```

IPv6 addresses must be surrounded in square brackets, as in the following example:

```
Listen [2001:db8::a00:20ff:fea7:ccea]:80
```

Answer (score 5):

What l1x said, plus, this is how you do both in a vhost:

```
<VirtualHost 74.208.184.120:80 [2001:470:c083:1::1]:80>
```

Preferably with your IPs instead of mine :)

Comment: Yeah, rite, if he wants vhosts.

Comment: I don't know when the last time I configured an apache instance that didn't have vhosts was, so I always assume it :)

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to use two separate Listen directives on a dual-stack host Apache refused to start, with an error like something had already bound on port 80. Surely this is a bug, but I had success by using this:

```
Listen          "*:80"
```